# How to check if discord bot is in channel?

Tags: python, pip, discord

I kinda made this working music bot code, it join vc and play the song. But when its in voice it wont play another one, i need to disconnect him. I want that he play next song even if he is joined. How to do it?

code(part where i want the thing):

```
@bot.command()
async def hraj(ctx, url):
    if not ctx.message.author.voice:
        await ctx.send("Musíš být ve voicu ty pepego!")
        return

    else:
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel

    await channel.connect()

    server = ctx.message.guild
    voice_channel = server.voice_client

    async with ctx.typing():
        player = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=bot.loop)
        voice_channel.play(player, after=lambda e: print("Error. %s" %e if e else None))

    e = discord.Embed(title="Právě hraje:", description=f"[{player.title}]({url})", color=0x0091ff)
    e.set_footer(text="Lets go jdem vibovat <333")
    await ctx.send(embed=e)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```py
voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
if voice == None:
   channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
```

This works because `discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)` returns `None` if your bot isn't in a voice channel.

So your code would be:

```py
@bot.command()
async def hraj(ctx, url):
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice == None:
       channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    else:
        await ctx.send('Musíš být ve voicu' ty pepego)

    await channel.connect()

    server = ctx.message.guild
    voice_channel = server.voice_client

    async with ctx.typing():
        player = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=bot.loop)
        voice_channel.play(player, after=lambda e: print("Error. %s" %e if e else None))

    e = discord.Embed(title="Právě hraje:", description=f"[{player.title}]({url})", color=0x0091ff)
    e.set_footer(text="Lets go jdem vibovat <333")
    await ctx.send(embed=e)
```

Your question wasn't very clear btw.

Comment: Like i just want to make some working music bot :D. And thx now it works